# Qt5: connect: How to use 'connect' in case the slot has less parameters than the signal

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

Task is to connect from one signal with one parameter to a slot with zero parameters. With the "old" Qt4-way of connect it works like this

```
connect(object1, SIGNAL(signal(int param)), object2, SLOT(slot()))
```

**But what if I want to use the type-safe Qt5-connects?**

The documentation just mentions the cases with:

- connect to default parameters in slot
- and using the above-mentioned way of the stringbased connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A slot can take less arguments than provided by the signal, HOW? - Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363256/a-slot-can-take-less-arguments-than-provided-by-the-signal-how-qt)

Comment: No, because I wanted the Qt5-way without SIGNAL/SLOT in the syntax. Also without using an additional "buffer"-slot. Therefore the answer from bunto1 is the fitting one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Qt5-style connect mechanism ignores extra-arguments of the signal just like you could specify in the Qt4-style:

> The signals and slots mechanism is type safe: The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot. **(In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it receives because it can ignore extra arguments.)** Since the signatures are compatible, the compiler can help us detect type mismatches when using the function pointer-based syntax. The string-based SIGNAL and SLOT syntax will detect type mismatches at runtime.

From the [Qt Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots) (emphasis mine).

So you can use the new style like this:

```
connect(&object1, &ClassObject1::signal, &object2, &ClassObject2::slot);
```

Comment: After seeing your comment, I tried this situation again and it compiles. I am compelled and guess that my initial code had some other kind of issue (which I interpreted wrong). Thank you.

Comment: @MarcelPetrick if either method is overloaded, it will complain about ambiguity. You may have to `qOverload<int>(&ClassObject1::signal)` or similar

Answer (score 0):

You can connect as the Qt4-Way without problems. The only thing you can't do is connect with the slot having less params.

Comment: But using the new type safe syntax is much preferred since it detects more problems at compile time and is also faster at run time.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think he meant "You can use the type-safe connect as you would do it the Qt4-Way without problems."

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found a way to handle this without declaring and defining an additional slot: the solution is to use a lambda, to fizzle out the additionals parameter(s).

Example (in case of object2 is our own project (this).
Following the style of the naming like in the question:

```
connect(object1, &Object1::signal, [this](int) { slot(); } );
```